# jest with enzyme testing shallow stucks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to test a component in react native, but it gets stuck on the shallow test. If I pass an incorrect component, the test fails, but if I pass a react-native text component it gets stuck.

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, {shallow, mount} from "enzyme";
import Screen from 'react-native-login'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import {Text} from 'react-native'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

test('render with react-native component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Text />); // Hangs
})
```